# what is the unit of the following standardization formula?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

If normalization would be to rescale the range of values to scale between $0$ and $1$ as follow:

$x^{'}=\frac{x-\min(x)}{\max(x)-\min(x)}$
where the interval of $x^{'}$ is closed between $[0,1]$

where $x$ is the actual value and $x^{'}$ is the normalized value.

If $z$-score standardization would be to transform the features to have zero mean and unit variance as follow:

$x^{'} = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$

where $x^{'}$ is the $z$-score, $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the variance. The unit of this $z$-score would be $\sigma$.

**Now my question**, what would be the unit of the following formula?

$x^{'}=\frac{x-\mu}{\max(x)-\min(x)}$

where $x^{'}$ is the standardized value, $\mu$ is the mean and $\max(x)$, $\min(x)$ are the maximum and minimum values respectively.

I know it will have an open interval between $0$ and $1$, as in $(0,1)$, but its not clear for me what the unit is, or what the unit mean.

Any shining light would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably familiar with the interpretation of the $z$ score as "the number of standard deviations the test statistic is from the mean". This interpretation can be obtained from the formula for the $z$ score.

Consider,

$$z = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma},$$

if we multiply $\sigma$ to the left hand side we get,

$$ z \sigma = x-\mu,$$

here we see that $x-\mu$ is equal to the standard deviation $z$ times.

There is a similar interpretation for your variable $x'$.

The definition of $x'$ is,

$$ x' = \frac{x-\mu}{\text{range}},$$

we can once again multiply the range to the left hand side obtaining,

$$ x' \text{range} = x-\mu.$$

Here we see that $x-\mu$ is equal to the range $x'$ times. In other words $x'$ is the fraction of the range which makes up the distance between $x$ and $\mu$.

Comment: This is a great explanation. So if I understand correctly, the larger the $range$ the lower the $x^{'}$, which makes this standardization more sensitive to outliers as in comparision to the $z$-score?

Comment: Yes this is true. Thank you for the compliment.

Comment: Ok than i got. Thanks again